# Making one TextView object overlap another, using xml attributes

Tags: android

I want TextView displayDate to be displayed overlapping TextView selectDate, only using xml attributes. How can this be done? If not possible how can it be (simply) done through coding?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayDate"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="209dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="209dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="438dp"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectedDate"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="236dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="236dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="418dp"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Overlapping views is not much of common sense.

Comment: It is, that is if you have the common sense of appreciating screen layout esthetics. Are you going to be helpful, or are you merely interested in voting people's questions down?

Comment: I **did not** vote your question down. I'm just telling you that overlapping views is not a common sense way of laying out your UI. You can achieve similar results by **faking** overlapping. Mostly by using nested Views. Which is a common practice and will lead to a **much cleaner** UI and UX..